# Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I want to create a JUnit test for this private method:

```
@Component
public class ReportingProcessor {

    @EventListener
    private void collectEnvironmentData(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class ReportingTest {

    @Autowired
    ReportingProcessor reportingProcessor;

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws Exception {

        ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent = PowerMockito.mock(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(reportingProcessor, "collectEnvironmentData", contextRefreshedEvent);

    }
}
```

When I run the code I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

Do you know ho I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a class annotated with `SpringBootApplication` or `SpringBootConfiguration`?

Comment: YOur test won't work. If it would the processor would already be invoked. Do you want to test the class/logic or the fact that it is triggered upon starting your application. That isn't clear from your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and the known `main()` method, you need to target your component class on the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Usually I do this when I'm building libraries and for some specific scenario I need to have the spring context to unit test them.

Just add this to your code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ReportingTest.class)
public class ReportingTest {
...
```

In JUnit 5 `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is not needed

Comment: I get this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441701/illegal-reflective-access-by-org-powermock-reflect-internal-whiteboximpl-to-meth

Comment: Replied! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

For future lost souls: in my case reason of this exception was that I created Junit test without package specified.

Your test must be in subpackage of your main spring class (one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`). So if you have `com.example.Application` then your test must be in some sub package, for example `com.example.subpackage`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@RunWith` with your `@SpringBootTest`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ReportingTest {

    @Autowired
    ReportingProcessor reportingProcessor;

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws Exception {

        ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent = PowerMockito.mock(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(reportingProcessor, "collectEnvironmentData", contextRefreshedEvent);

    }
}
```

Comment: I get again `ReportingTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration`