# Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl to method java.lang.Object.clone()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, powermock

I want to use this JUnit test for testing private method:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ReportingProcessor.class)
public class ReportingTest {

    @Autowired
    ReportingProcessor reportingProcessor;

    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws Exception {

        ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent = PowerMockito.mock(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(reportingProcessor, "collectEnvironmentData", contextRefreshedEvent);

    }
}
```

But I get `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl (file:/C:/Users/Mainuser/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/2.0.2/powermock-reflect-2.0.2.jar) to method java.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release`

Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There are already a few questions about it:

[what is an illegal reflective access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251798/what-is-an-illegal-reflective-access)

[JDK9: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred. org.python.core.PySystemState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230413/jdk9-an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-org-python-core-pysys/46230678)

and a few more.

For testing purposes, you can just perform the reflection from your side, with no need to use dependencies. I have changed the return type of the collectEnvironmentData method just for a better understanding:

```
 @EventListener
 private String collectEnvironmentData(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    return "Test";
 }
```

You can achieve the pretended result by accessing it this way:

```
    @Test
    public void reportingTest() throws Exception {

        ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent = PowerMockito.mock(ContextRefreshedEvent.class);

        Method privateMethod = ReportingProcessor.class.
                getDeclaredMethod("collectEnvironmentData", ContextRefreshedEvent.class);

        privateMethod.setAccessible(true);

        String returnValue = (String)
                privateMethod.invoke(reportingProcessor, contextRefreshedEvent);
        Assert.assertEquals("Test", returnValue);
    }
```

No warnings on my console, with JDK13.

Comment: When I compile the entire project it's running well. But when I compile only this JUnit test I get `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)`

Comment: Check if you are using the right annotation: import org.junit.Test;

Comment: I removed @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and now it's working fine. Is this correct?